# Select Columns from table A based on columns in table B (SAS)

Tags: mysql, sas

So I have two tables that I use to create a third table. Table A has columns A, B, C, D, and 1 through 100; think a list of insurance claims and their top *billed* codes. Table B has columns E, F, G, H and 1 through 100 (with some columns in 1 - 100 missing); think a list of coefficients on insurance claims, and their top *adjustment* codes. So, table A always has columns A, B, C, D, and 1 through 100, and table B always has columns E, F, G, H, but can have any variety of columns 1 through 100 - ie some missing columns in 1-100.

I have to join these tables and construct some summary values as follows:

```
Proc Sql;
Create table C as Select
a.A,
a.B,
a.C,
a.D, 
abs(a.1 x b.1 + 
    a.2 x b.2 + 
    a.3 x b.3 +....+ 
    a.100 x b.100 + 
    a.D x b.E + b.F) x a.C as Expected_Ratio
from A as a, B as b;
```

Because of the volume of columns, I include all of a.i x b.i in the code. But if b.i doesn't exist, obviously errors occur.

So say this month I have values 1 through 100, but 17, 37, 57, and 89 are missing in B; I run the code and get errors for the missing values 17, 37, 57, and 89 - which I then comment out. I then rerun and get my desired output. This leads to a lot of time reviewing the log looking for which values are kicking out the errors, and then commenting out the missing values. And this has to be done each time the code is run.

Is there any way to automate the summary function to avoid the errors? Or a way to handle the errors so that the code can ignore a.i x b.i when column i isn't in table b? If the missing values were objects in either table, I know I could do a subquery of "where a.* in (select b.* from b)" but since these are columns I don't know how to handle the select clause.

I basically just need a way to say sum the product of a.i and b.i, but only if i exists in both a and b...

Comment: I think what you are basically saying is that the database was badly designed. Can it be corrected?

Comment: Sounds like you just want to use the SAS SUM(,) function instead of the addition operator.  That will ignore the missing values when generating the total.

Comment: Show some example data. I think arrays and a data step will work better for you than SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the 'badly designed' comment. Basically, in billed claims we have every possible code, but in top adjusted claims we have a finite number of codes. I want to match the billed codes to the adjusted codes to get a coefficient. I don't think that has anything to do with poor data constructs, it's just the way it is...

Comment: As far as sample data, I can't really share that for a multitude of reasons. Is there an explicit question on my explanation of the issue? I think I explain the layout and issue as best as I can there....

Comment: You do not need to share REAL data.  Just any data that demonstrates your issue.  For example there is no need to include more than two or three variables to demonstrate the issue that can be expanded to 100 or more variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match values by the "column number" then it would be much easier to have the data in a TALL format where "column number" is an actual variable that can be used in the matching instead of the NAME of a varaible.

```
data A;
  input A B C D column value ;
cards;
1 2 3 4 1 100
1 2 3 5 2 80
;

data B;
  input E F column multiplier ;
cards;
5 6 1 .50
5 6 2 .25
5 6 3 .15 
;

proc sql ;
  create table want as 
    select a.A,a.B,a.C,a.D
         , abs(sum( sum(a.value*b.multiplier) , a.D*b.E, b.F)) as Expected_Ratio
    from A a left join B b 
    on a.column = b.column
    group by a.A,a.B,a.C,a.D
  ;
quit;
```

Result

```
                           Expected_
Obs    A    B    C    D      Ratio

 1     1    2    3    4        76
 2     1    2    3    5        51
```

You can use PROC TRANSPOSE to convert from your "WIDE" format to this "TALL" format.  Just make sure you have key variables that uniquely identify the rows in A and B that you can use in the BY statement for PROC TRANSPOSE.